# How to check if a div bloc is visible and hide another div if so

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(".imageright").function();
    if ( jQuery(".bloc_3").is(":visible") ) {
      jQuery(".imageright").hide();
    };
});
```

why is this code note working?

Comment: this should happen on some event (click etc), if yes then what is that event?

Comment: don't need the HTML to see there's a syntax error

Comment: You're closing off the statement in the very first line with that semicolon (which is also syntactically wrong). After that, more syntax errors.

Comment: but in first line there isn't any trigger? isn't

Comment: You're setup of defining this function is completely wrong

Comment: What is `.imageright`, it looks like it's supposed to be something a user interacts with but you didn't write the code correctly. Please explain WHEN this code is meant to run.

Comment: `$(".imageright").toggle(!$(".bloc_3").is(":visible"))` that's all she wrote

Answer (score 1):

something like this? Assuming that you want to hide the div at its click event if some other div is visible.

```
jQuery(".imageright").click( function(){
    if ( jQuery(".bloc_3").is(":visible") ) {
      jQuery(".imageright").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I was guessing too

Comment: @Popnoodles same here. Hopefully your comments will help him understand how to frame his question better from next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have major syntax errors here is those fixed

```
jQuery(".imageright").checkVisible=function(){
if ( jQuery(".bloc_3").is(":visible") ) {
  jQuery(".imageright").hide();
}
};
```

However it's hard to run functions attached to objects it would be easier just to assign it to a different variable and run it like this

```
Var checkVisible=function(){
if ( jQuery(".bloc_3").is(":visible") ) {
  jQuery(".imageright").hide();
}
};
checkVisible();
```

Comment: So he's supposed to execute `jQuery(".imageright").trigger("checkVisible");` at some point?

Comment: I don't know how the rest of his code is suppose to function that's just changing syntax errors

Comment: It's a fair guess. I'd put my money on it meant to being on click function though

Comment: I added some clarification.

Comment: Can someone clarify the down Vote? I see no clear reason for it.